# How can every user have his private doctrine entries in a symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am creating an application with guests, venues, events and guest-categories in symfony2 with doctrine. Being in touch for 3 weeks only with symfony2, I have accomplished to create the schema tables for all entities in sql, their between dependencies and crud for each one. My problem is more theoretical than practical.

I will create a bundle for security (from the Security bundle in the book or FOSUserBundle). Then I will set up three roles:

- Administrator
- Organiser
- Guest

Each guest will have its own profile and each organiser will be "attached" to his guests - in simple words, the Organizer X will only communicate and view Guest X-1, X-2 etc. - he won't be able to view Y-1. It might seem very simple and funny to you that I am asking a question like that but... I am self taught :)

The question is: How can I attach an event to an organiser and its guests? The simplest method I can imagine is : set a unique token (or any self generated code) for every guest, event, category, event and join the tables.

If guest John with token=vsfv2435r3frwf24t5grf has any events/categories/venues
find the same token in the event or category or venue and assign permissions.

Does it sound logical or foolish ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create cross table for `Organiser` and `Guest` indicating which event they do attend / organise. Each `Guest` would also have have cross table to `Organiser`. This way you could easily assign organisers to guests and filter by it (I'm assuming guests could attend multiple events etc).

In Doctrine world it'd look like this:

**Event**

```
...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Organiser", inversedBy="events")
 */
protected $organisers;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Guest", inversedBy="events")
 */
protected $guests;
```

**Organiser**

```
...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Event", mappedBy="organisers")
 */
protected $events;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Guest", mappedBy="organisers")
 */
protected $guests;
```

**Guest**

```
...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Event", mappedBy="guests")
 */
protected $events;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Organiser", inversedBy="guests")
 */
protected $organisers;
```

Comment: I have already done this. I might not have been clear to my explanation. I have set up the relationships successfully and created the db schema. The question is :

In the db you will have 
1. john john 
2. jim jim 

as organisers. Then John John logs in and is able to insert some guests. He logs out and Jim jim logs in. He inserts some guests also. How will the system know which entries are for who ? In fact, when a ADMIN ROLE is given to jim jim or john john, it will be to insert, view or delete entries. How will I give permissions to the SPECIFIC entries that each one created ?

Comment: Or else everyone that has view permissions,  will view ALL entries.

Comment: I suppose I will have to create a new table ? Or it clears out in the select query ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at doctrine association mapping (one to many, many to many, etc.. )

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html

They are quite easy to set up (you can do it in Symfony with a annotations or in your yml schema file) and will let you do the kind of things you are describing easily, take  a look at the Symfony documentation for databases for more info

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html